# How to Consider Value in Varchar Variable as New Variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have n input parameters to my procedure & I have to perform some operation on all those variables:

Code :

```
DECLARE
p_Input1 VARCHAR2(10) := 'Nagendra';
p_Input2 VARCHAR2(10) :='';
p_Input3 VARCHAR2(10) :='Nagendra';
p_Input4 VARCHAR2(10) :='';
Temp_Input_Variable VARCHAR2(12);
Temp_Output_Variable VARCHAR2(12);
BEGIN 

For i IN 1..4
Loop
Temp_Input_Variable := 'p_Input'||i;
IF ( Temp_Input_Variable IS NOT NULL ) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Variable '||Temp_Input_Variable||' Is Not Null');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Variable '||Temp_Input_Variable||' Is Null');
END IF;
END LOOP;

END;
```

Output :

```
Variable p_Input1 Is Not Null
Variable p_Input2 Is Not Null
Variable p_Input3 Is Not Null
Variable p_Input4 Is Not Null
```

Expected Output :

```
Variable p_Input1 Is Not Null
Variable p_Input2 Is Null
Variable p_Input3 Is Not Null
Variable p_Input4 Is Null
```

The problem here is , whenever I am checking `Temp_Input_Variable IS NOT NULL` , it simply checks for the value of is variable is not null , which is right.

But instead of this , I want to use value of this variable as New variable and not null should be applied on that.

So `Temp_Input_Variable IS NOT NULL` should be considered as `p_Input1 IS NOT NULL` Not Like `'p_Input1' IS NOT NULL`

All this to perform all this operations in loop & avoid repeat work/code.

Please Suggest.

**Update :**
Thanks for suggestions.

I have around ~30 inputs & may change in future.

So what I am looking for is to call through loop like `Work(P_InputN)` instead of calling `Work(p_Input1)` `Work(P_Input2)` and so on.

Even though working of code will be same , but what I personally think that code with loop is good for look & feel.

Comment: You cannot to form a variable dynamically like that. As I understood, you want to assign values of a static `p_inputN` variable to the `Temp_Input_Variable`  dynamically, no, it cannot be done that way. One of the option is to use collections. Create a collection, each element of a collection will represent your `pinputN` variable, and then loop through that collection assigning its element to the `Temp_Input_variable` variable if you really need to do so.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something you can loop through, then you'll need either an array or possibly (more complicated) a database table.

```
declare
    type varchar2_tt is table of varchar2(12) index by pls_integer;
    p_input varchar2_tt;

    temp_input_variable  varchar2(12);
begin
    p_input(1) := 'Nagendra';
    p_input(2) := '';
    p_input(3) := 'Nagendra';
    p_input(4) := '';

    for i in 1 .. 4 loop
        temp_input_variable := p_input(i);

        dbms_output.put_line
        ( i || ': temp_input_variable = ''' || temp_input_variable || ''' (' ||
          case when temp_input_variable is not null then 'not ' end || 'null)' );
    end loop;
end;
/

1: temp_input_variable = 'Nagendra' (not null)
2: temp_input_variable = '' (null)
3: temp_input_variable = 'Nagendra' (not null)
4: temp_input_variable = '' (null)
```

You could index the associative array by a string instead of a number, if that would help, e.g. `p_input('NAME') = 'Nagendra'`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the wrong way to go about achieving your aims. Instead, I would create a procedure to do the actual work, and then pass in the relevant values as needs be, something like:

```
DECLARE
  p_input1 VARCHAR2(10) := 'Nagendra';
  p_input2 VARCHAR2(10) := '';
  p_input3 VARCHAR2(10) := 'Nagendra';
  p_input4 VARCHAR2(10) := '';

  PROCEDURE do_work (p_input IN VARCHAR2,
                     p_variable_name IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF (p_input IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Variable ' || p_variable_name ||
                   ' Is Not Null');
    ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Variable ' || p_variable_name || ' Is Null');
    END IF;
  END do_work;
BEGIN
  do_work(p_input1, 'p_input1');
  do_work(p_input2, 'p_input2');
  do_work(p_input3, 'p_input3');
  do_work(p_input4, 'p_input4');
END;
/

Variable p_input1 Is Not Null
Variable p_input2 Is Null
Variable p_input3 Is Not Null
Variable p_input4 Is Null
```

Another alternative would be to use a collection:

```
DECLARE  
  TYPE v_assoc_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  v_tab v_assoc_array;
  i INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_tab(1) := 'Nagendra';
  v_tab(2) := NULL;
  v_tab(3) := 'Nagendra';
  v_tab(4) := NULL;

  i := v_tab.first;

  WHILE i IS NOT NULL
  LOOP
    IF (v_tab(i) IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Input ' || i ||
                   ' Is Not Null');
    ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Input ' || i || ' Is Null');
    END IF;

    i := v_tab.next(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Input 1 Is Not Null
Input 2 Is Null
Input 3 Is Not Null
Input 4 Is Null
```

If neither of those are what you're after, please update your question with a more accurate description of what you're trying to achieve, and that should put us in a position to better help you.

Comment: Thank You. but  its not I am looking for. I have more inputs than just 4. To be precise around 30. & to perform many operations on all this variables. So I am looking for something that can Itself call in Loop.
Will Update the question